# Scanf returning unexpected value

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use `scanf` in a function.
In the first use, code is working fine, but in the second, `scanf` doesn't work.
Variable's value doesn't change, but I need to type something.
Here is a part of my code :

```
char *choix;
choix=(char *)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
printf("Saisissez le nom du fichier que vous voulez charger : ");
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
scanf("%s", choix);
lab=load(choix);
printf("\n%s\n",lab.nom);
free(choix);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What first and second `scanf`? In the code you provide there's only one. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?

Comment: It's a part of a function which is called several times by main program (user menu).

Comment: `while ( getchar() != '\n' );` remove the `;` maybe that's the problem? Try to indent your code to be properly read, and use `{}` even if you do just one statement.

Comment: I tried to remove ; and set {} at then end, but still have issue.
for exemple, when I put toto in twice, first time I've got "toto", seconde time, I've got "◄o".

Comment: After reading your code I have completely no idea what your code is supposed to do, neither what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I tried to set var `choix` in `lab.nom` without set `malloc` of `lab.nom`.

I just add `lab.nom=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(choix)+1));` and it's working fine.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `scanf()` for stuff like this, it's a bit hard to use.

Instead, use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read a whole line from the user, then parse that line if you need to. You can then remove the home-grown input flushing code.